# obiee write-back functionalities for direct database request

Tags: obiee

I followed all the steps described here:
http://obieetutorialguide.blogspot.be/2015/04/write-back-setting-in-obiee-11g.html
to be able to write back in an analyse where I do a "direct database request".
unfortunately the "write back" functionality stays grey and I can't check it.
Is it possible to writeback in a direct database request- analyse?

Answer (score 0):

Combining two of the decidedly "outlying" technologies inside of OBI in one single attempt - that is direct DB request and write-back - clearly shows one thing:

You aren't using the tool for what it was built: analytics.

What you want to do is probably right up the alley of Oracle APEX. Basically just a web application for data entry.

Comment: The purpose of my question is the following. We have a table with info/news that we want to publish on the home dashboard page. It is only info, no analytics, no facts, nothing. That's why I don't want it to be in the repository, because I can't link it to a fact table. That's why I want to do "direct database request". Administrators has to been able to add some extra news. Why are those technologies present, if we can't use them !

Comment: Because that's not their POINT. OBI is not a web application for data entry! Even if you were to make it work there is no way of field validation, pick lists or anything. No real handling for automatic ID creation. Nothing.

What you are describing is diametrically opposite to the purpose of an analytical application which READS information and makes sense of it. It does not CREATE information and arbitrarily enters it into a database. That is exactly what APEX is for.